# Splunk integration with HoneyD

Tags: honeypot, siem

In a previous thread someone mentioned about HoneyD causing logs to fill up too fast, there was a comment posted about using splunk.

I am very interested in how to integrate HoneyD with Splunk, it doesn't come with a built in integration module like Modern Honeypot Network does.

Does anyone know about this and has maybe implemented this themselves (if you have done it, or it might have just been a concept)?

Comment: This is probably best suited for Spunks support forums.  https://answers.splunk.com/index.html

Comment: https://github.com/aplura/Tango